# XML value log gives 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following JS code:

```
let xmlStr = '<books><book><name>Ivan Zvonar</name><title>Vanya</title></book></books>';

console.log(xmlStr);

let parser = new DOMParser();

xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");

let name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");

console.log(name.textContent);
```

When I am trying to log the very object 'name' - it works, but when its value - it gives me 'undefined' in console.

Please help, who can. I statred learning XML only today;

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of elements. In your case, You have to use `["0"]` to get the value.

```js
let xmlStr = '<books><book><name>Ivan Zvonar</name><title>Vanya</title></book></books>';

let parser = new DOMParser();

xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");

let names = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")

console.log(names["0"].textContent)
```

Comment: Great! Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)